# Reading CSV with sparsely labeled column headers using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv I am trying to read into a pandas data frame that has multiple rows of column headers, but the first row is sparsely labeled.

ex:

```
Binned_average_and_predicted_H2O_spectra_sorted_by_RH-class.,,,,,,,,
,RH=0.8,,,,RH=0.9,,,
,n_=_60,,,,n_=_29,,,
nat_freq,avrg_sp(T),avrg_sp(h2o),denoised_avrg_sp(h2o),pred_sp(h2o),avrg_sp(T),avrg_sp(h2o),denoised_avrg_sp(h2o),pred_sp(h2o)
6.10E-04,8.40E-02,0.117551351,0.117550357,8.64E-02,0.128696811,0.163304381,0.163304015,0.127552704
1.22E-03,7.49E-02,0.126467592,0.126465605,7.70E-02,9.05E-02,0.200350295,0.200349563,8.97E-02
1.83E-03,7.54E-02,0.124370072,0.124367091,7.76E-02,8.54E-02,0.121274897,0.121273799,8.46E-02
2.44E-03,7.76E-02,0.136590839,0.136586865,7.99E-02,5.45E-02,0.100995665,0.100994202,5.40E-02
3.05E-03,8.73E-02,0.141422799,0.141417832,8.98E-02,7.57E-02,0.170033442,0.170031614,7.50E-02
3.66E-03,7.29E-02,0.143599074,0.143593115,7.50E-02,0.10001777,0.165468366,0.165466173,9.91E-02
```

When I read the csv,

```
Cosp2 = pd.read_csv(DPath,index_col=0, header=[1,3])
print(Cosp2)
```

I end up with Unnamed: #_level_0 labels on all the headers first level headers that aren't explicit labeled.

```
             RH=0.8 Unnamed: 2_level_0    Unnamed: 3_level_0  \
nat_freq avrg_sp(T)       avrg_sp(h2o) denoised_avrg_sp(h2o)   
0.00061      0.0840           0.117551              0.117550   
0.00122      0.0749           0.126468              0.126466   
0.00183      0.0754           0.124370              0.124367   
0.00244      0.0776           0.136591              0.136587   
0.00305      0.0873           0.141423              0.141418   
0.00366      0.0729           0.143599              0.143593   

         Unnamed: 4_level_0     RH=0.9 Unnamed: 6_level_0  \
nat_freq       pred_sp(h2o) avrg_sp(T)       avrg_sp(h2o)   
0.00061              0.0864   0.128697           0.163304   
0.00122              0.0770   0.090500           0.200350   
0.00183              0.0776   0.085400           0.121275   
0.00244              0.0799   0.054500           0.100996   
0.00305              0.0898   0.075700           0.170033   
0.00366              0.0750   0.100018           0.165468   

            Unnamed: 7_level_0 Unnamed: 8_level_0  
nat_freq denoised_avrg_sp(h2o)       pred_sp(h2o)  
0.00061               0.163304           0.127553  
0.00122               0.200350           0.089700  
0.00183               0.121274           0.084600  
0.00244               0.100994           0.054000  
0.00305               0.170032           0.075000  
0.00366               0.165466           0.099100
```

Is there a way to get pandas to propagate the level 0 labels across the unlabeled columns?  I'd like something that looks like this:

```
             RH=0.8                                                  \
nat_freq avrg_sp(T) avrg_sp(h2o) denoised_avrg_sp(h2o) pred_sp(h2o)   
0.00061      0.0840     0.117551              0.117550       0.0864   
0.00122      0.0749     0.126468              0.126466       0.0770   
0.00183      0.0754     0.124370              0.124367       0.0776   
0.00244      0.0776     0.136591              0.136587       0.0799   
0.00305      0.0873     0.141423              0.141418       0.0898   
0.00366      0.0729     0.143599              0.143593       0.0750   

             RH=0.9                                                  
nat_freq avrg_sp(T) avrg_sp(h2o) denoised_avrg_sp(h2o) pred_sp(h2o)  
0.00061    0.128697     0.163304              0.163304     0.127553  
0.00122    0.090500     0.200350              0.200350     0.089700  
0.00183    0.085400     0.121275              0.121274     0.084600  
0.00244    0.054500     0.100996              0.100994     0.054000  
0.00305    0.075700     0.170033              0.170032     0.075000  
0.00366    0.100018     0.165468              0.165466     0.099100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) for `Series` first:

```
a = Cosp2.columns.get_level_values(0).to_series()
print (a)
RH=0.8                            RH=0.8
Unnamed: 2_level_0    Unnamed: 2_level_0
Unnamed: 3_level_0    Unnamed: 3_level_0
Unnamed: 4_level_0    Unnamed: 4_level_0
RH=0.9                            RH=0.9
Unnamed: 6_level_0    Unnamed: 6_level_0
Unnamed: 7_level_0    Unnamed: 7_level_0
Unnamed: 8_level_0    Unnamed: 8_level_0
dtype: object
```

Then use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for `NaN`s if [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) `Unnamed` and replace `NaN` by `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`)

```
b = a.mask(a.str.startswith('Unnamed')).ffill()
print (b)
RH=0.8                RH=0.8
Unnamed: 2_level_0    RH=0.8
Unnamed: 3_level_0    RH=0.8
Unnamed: 4_level_0    RH=0.8
RH=0.9                RH=0.9
Unnamed: 6_level_0    RH=0.9
Unnamed: 7_level_0    RH=0.9
Unnamed: 8_level_0    RH=0.9
dtype: object
```

Last create new `MultiIndex` by  [`from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
Cosp2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([b, Cosp2.columns.get_level_values(1)])
print (Cosp2)
             RH=0.8                                                  \
nat_freq avrg_sp(T) avrg_sp(h2o) denoised_avrg_sp(h2o) pred_sp(h2o)   
0.00061      0.0840     0.117551              0.117550       0.0864   
0.00122      0.0749     0.126468              0.126466       0.0770   
0.00183      0.0754     0.124370              0.124367       0.0776   
0.00244      0.0776     0.136591              0.136587       0.0799   
0.00305      0.0873     0.141423              0.141418       0.0898   
0.00366      0.0729     0.143599              0.143593       0.0750   

             RH=0.9                                                  
nat_freq avrg_sp(T) avrg_sp(h2o) denoised_avrg_sp(h2o) pred_sp(h2o)  
0.00061    0.128697     0.163304              0.163304     0.127553  
0.00122    0.090500     0.200350              0.200350     0.089700  
0.00183    0.085400     0.121275              0.121274     0.084600  
0.00244    0.054500     0.100996              0.100994     0.054000  
0.00305    0.075700     0.170033              0.170032     0.075000  
0.00366    0.100018     0.165468              0.165466     0.099100
```